# OBIEE remove dimension value based on measure result

Tags: obiee

One of my dimension contains the different divisions of the company. I have one division which doesn't exist anymore but I want to keep this to check the results of previous years and months. 
How do I dynamically eliminate this value of the dimension when it doesn't have a measure anymore? 
First I was thinking that adding a filter where the measure should be > 0 or 'not null' but this doesn't seem to do the trick. The dimension keeps showing up.

Thanks!

Comment: "dynamically eliminate this value of the dimension when it doesn't have a measure anymore" <-- in what way? When a list of values is displayed?

Comment: Are you needing the rows corresponding to that obsolete division to be excluded from the analysis when the year is greater than 2014?

Comment: Not really hardcoded when the year is bigger than 2014, just when the measure is 0 or null it shouldn't show up anymore. I want this to be dynamic because other divisions may disappear as well in the future and I want this report to keep working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To go a bit into more details on Robin's question which is the most pertinent one:

Do you try to remove the "obsolete" dimension member from dimension-only queries - like prompts for example?

This is crucial to know as forcing a normally dimension-only query over a fact and thus continuously forcing the inclusion of the fact table for all queries potentially has quite a performance impact.

a) ">0" and "is not null are two completely different things and if used in a cavalier fashion can also yield absolutely wrong results. What if the measure is at a negative value? That would make it "disappear" as well for you. What if there simply is no measure yet but the dimension member is implicitly actually valid just not filled yet? That would also make it disappear for you.

b) How can you know the point of view a user is standing at? For an analysis run for last year this will be perfectly valid to show?

c) What about time-variant comparisons? What about rolling calculations?

d) What about the point-in-time of the dimension rather than the fact? --v

e) What about cross-org analysis like "What do our numbers look like when we apply last year's org vs this year's vs a planned new one which is already loaded into the data source?

While I understand the idea behind your question you should not forget that we're talking analytics here and always face changing dimensions and attributes so your request which seems valid from a human point of view for that one, specific use case is - for the solution as a whole - to be considered wisely.

Comment: I still want to see the value when requesting this report in history, e.g. this division still existed in 2014 so when I request the report for 2014, I want to see it. I don't want to hardcode remove this value (also that would be very easy). But this value keeps showing up even though it doesn't have any value in the year 2017. 
I also understand that 'is not null' is not the same as > 0 but in this particular example of mine a null always means that it's equal to 0. But I know that 'null' stands for 'any random value' so can be treated another way, that's why I tried these different ways.

Comment: "But this value keeps showing up even though it doesn't have any value in the year 2017."

^-- The question is "where" or "in which context" because it is a valid value. If you just want to remove it from - let's say prompts for example. Then you can either put time limitations on the query that's being run.

But forcing the query over the fact is something you should really think about in detail because obviously performance impact on the query is something totally different.

Answer (score -1):

Although I'm not clear on what you mean by "eliminate this value of the dimension", I think you may be looking for the [pivot measure function](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/filter_function), called `FILTER(Fact USING (Insert your filter here))`.

I am assuming that when aggregating using a measure, your problem is that you are unable to exclude the Division that does not exist anymore, and as a result, your measures/aggregations are incorrect.

In this case, you should use the pivot measure as I indicate above.

---

Your column formula would look like this:

**`FILTER(Measure1 USING ("SubjectArea1"."Division" <> 'DivisionName'))`**

---

**Follow these steps to implement this function:**

1. Edit the column formula of your measure.
2. Highlight the formula of the column and click the **`Filter...`** button at the bottom of the Column Formula text box. An **Insert Filter** window will appear.
3. Select the Division column from the Subject Areas pane. (Either double-click it, or select it then click the `OK` button).
4. You will see a **New Filter** window. Change the **Operator** to `is not equal to / is not in`.
5. Select your Division that you want to exclude.
6. Click `OK` to close the **New Filter** window.
7. Click `OK` again to close the **Insert Filter** window.
8. Click `OK` again to close the **Edit Column Formula** window.
9. If your syntax is correct, you will see no errors.

Comment: I know of this filter function, however this can only be used for a measure. I have a dimension which contains a value I don't want to see anymore.